# Laravel マイグレーション時にMySQLへのアクセス拒否が発生した

Tags: mysql, laravel

以前、質問した[MySQLの新しいパスワード設定の際のパスワードポリシー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/95672/mysql%e3%81%ae%e6%96%b0%e3%81%97%e3%81%84%e3%83%91%e3%82%b9%e3%83%af%e3%83%bc%e3%83%89%e8%a8%ad%e5%ae%9a%e3%81%ae%e9%9a%9b%e3%81%ae%e3%83%91%e3%82%b9%e3%83%af%e3%83%bc%e3%83%89%e3%83%9d%e3%83%aa%e3%82%b7%e3%83%bc)に続いた質問になるのですが、Laravelでマイグレーションをコマンドから行い、ユーザーの作成とデータベースの作成を試みたのですが、アクセス拒否のエラーが発生しました。

mysqlのパスワードポリシーはLOWにして、文字列を4文字以上に変更しました。
そして.envファイルのmysqlに関する記述は以下のようになっていました。
・現在のパスワードポリシー

```
mysql> show variables like 'validate_password%';
+--------------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                        | Value |
+--------------------------------------+-------+
| validate_password.check_user_name    | ON    |
| validate_password.dictionary_file    |       |
| validate_password.length             | 4     |
| validate_password.mixed_case_count   | 1     |
| validate_password.number_count       | 1     |
| validate_password.policy             | LOW   |
| validate_password.special_char_count | 1     |
+--------------------------------------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

・.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=myapp
DB_USERNAME=DBuser
DB_PASSWORD=DBuser
```

マイグレーションの実行時のエラーはこちらになります。

```
ec2-user:~/environment/myapp $ php artisan migrate 

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'DBuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = myapp and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671
    667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 671|             throw new QueryException(
    672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673|             );
    674|         }
    675| 

      +33 vendor frames 
  34  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

そこでmysqlのDB_HOSTやDB_PORTを変更して、試してみたのですが、エラーは変わりませんでした。

このアクセス拒否のエラーを調べると、パスワードの不整合さや、ログインが出来ないということも原因だと思ったのですが、rootからログインもでき、パスワードも先述のようにパスワードポリシーを変更し、パスワードポリシーに抵触しないパスワードにしたつもりです。
パスワードポリシーの変更はrootだけに適応されたのでしょうか？

[php artisan migrateが上手く行かなかった時の対処法/SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045]](https://terrblog.com/php-artisan-migrate%E3%81%8C%E4%B8%8A%E6%89%8B%E3%81%8F%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E6%99%82%E3%81%AE%E5%AF%BE%E5%87%A6%E6%B3%95-sqlstatehy000-1045/)

Mysqlバージョン：mysql  Ver 8.0.33 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
Laravelバージョン：Laravel Framework 7.30.6

Comment: 質問の本題とは離れますが、DB のログインパスワードを弱くすることはセキュリティ観点でおすすめできません。特に本番環境でこのような設定にはしない方が良いことが多いです。何かしらの脆弱性で DB サーバーにリクエストできるときにログインも出来ちゃう可能性が高まるため、よりクリティカルな攻撃が成功しやすくなってしまいます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。それではミディアムに戻したいと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel からではなく MySQL クライアントから DBuser としてログインできるか確認してみてください。たとえば `mysql -u DBuser -p -h 127.0.0.1` でログインできますか。質問文の書き方から見るに、もしかして MySQL 側で DBuser ユーザーを作成していないのではないかと疑っています。まずは DB サーバー側でユーザーを作成してください。

Laravel のマイグレーションの一般論については公式ドキュメントを置いておきます: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations

Comment: ログインできませんでした。ec2-user:~/environment/myapp $ mysql -u DBuser -p -h 127.0.0.1
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'DBuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: 今、rootからログインをしたところ、パスワードポリシーがミディアムに勝手に戻っていました。ミディアムに合わせて、.envのデータベースの記述を変えてみます。

Comment: DB_PASSWORD=DBuser-24に変えて、試してみたのですが、同様のエラーが発生しました。

Comment: では DBuser ユーザーを作っていないのではないでしょうか。

Comment: はい。 php artisan migrate を行えばDBuserも作成されると思っていたのですが、一度mysqlでDBuserを作成してから php artisan migrate を行うのが正しいい手順ですか？

Comment: DB マイグレーションとは何であるかについて誤解があるようです。公式ドキュメントをご覧ください: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations　／　DB のユーザーは事前に作る必要があります。もし Laravel が DB ユーザーを作れるのだとすると、ユーザーを作るための認証情報を Laravel が持っていることになりますが、何も渡していないため Laravel がユーザーを作ることは出来ません。

Comment: 新しくDBuserを作成し、ログインできました。しかしマイグレーションを行うと今度は不明な認証と出ました。 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = myapp and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Comment: 上記のエラーを調べてみたところ、データベースを作成していない事が原因かもしれないので、データベースを作成してみます。